# Shell Flyout Menu not showing all the Menu Items All the time in .NET MAUI Windows

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I am working with App Shell Menu Flyout to display menu items, but the menu items all are not showing all the time.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Step 1: Created the .NET MAUI application and Create a page with Shell to display the menu flyout below is the code.

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Home" 
                  Icon="icon_home.png">
        <views:HomePage/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="System Status" 
                  Icon="menu_icon_sysstatus.png">
        <views:SystemStatusPage/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="System Setup" 
                  Icon="menu_icon_syssetup.png">
        <views:SystemSetupPage/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="Settings" 
                  Icon="menu_icon_settings.png">
        <views:SettingsPage/>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Step 2: When I run the application in windows For the first time when the flyout menu is showing all the menu items and Home Page as selected one as below Image.

[image]

Step 3: After that when I select System Status Menu Item it is not showing Settings and About Menu Items

[image]

**Expected Behavior**

It should display all the menu item all the time when menu flyout open.

**Basic Information**

Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 Preview 2.0

I have added a Reproducible example in the git [Git Link](https://github.com/deviprasad987/ShellPOC.git)

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?

Comment: @Alexandar May - MSFT
I have added Reproducible example in the git https://github.com/deviprasad987/ShellPOC.git

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that was already reported here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6061.

There are mainly two ways to fix the issue.

`WORKAROUND 1:`
What you have to do is just add a header to the flyout(I chose to use `header`  instead of `footer`). If you don't have anything in the header, just add this below:

```
   <Shell.FlyoutHeader >
        <Grid MaximumHeightRequest="1"/>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>
```

`WORKAROUND 2:`
Hot reload fixes this, but if you want to fix that in the app itself, you can add a Button [to flyout header or footer] or TapGestureRecognizer [still on header or footer], and in the function behind it just add something like this below:

```
if(FlyoutWidth == original_size)
            FlyoutWidth = original_size-10;
        else
            FlyoutWidth = original_size;
```

Comment: I have tried above Workarounds but it is not working

Comment: I think the issue still exits https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7033

Comment: Thanks for the update. Then you can follow up there:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7033.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work with MaximumHeightRequest="1" but it did work with a value greater than 30

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeader >
    <Grid MaximumHeightRequest="31"/>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>
```

Comment: For me it's not working, could you provide working sample

Answer (score 0):

I can get the problem to "go away" by implementing an **ItemTemplate**...

```
   <ShellContent
        Title="EXIT"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ExitPage}"
        Route="ExitPage">
        <Shell.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Margin="0" Padding="0">
                    <Label FontSize="18" Text="EXIT" />
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Shell.ItemTemplate>
    </ShellContent>
```

However, once you start adding any type of formatting specifiers, such as VerticalOptions or HorizontalOptions, the problem comes back.